# CFBundleIdentifier not found when cloned from git

Tags: react-native-ios

I have my app running fine but whenever I clone my own git repo and run: 
`react-native run-ios` (after installing node modules and pod of course)

the terminal throws me with an error that the: `cfbundleidentifier was not found`.

But when I replace the build folder of my recently cloned app with the working version of my app it runs perfectly fine.

I have already tried to `npm run rename` to change the bundle identifier of my project.

I also have my `googleService-info.plist` file inside my ios folder and also the `info.plist` inside my `ios/user` folder.

Comment: Did you check the port 8081? Maybe it is already in use. Try write `lsof -n -i4TCP:8081` in command line. If you see output which is start with `node <PID> ...`, you can kill that process with `kill - 9 <PID>`. See also [https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/troubleshooting.html]

Comment: Yes I tried doing that still no success!!!